# multiple xml body insert into oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-loader

Requiremet - have multiple xml root body in a file and would like to load every root body into a separate row in XMLtype oracle table

for example.

```
<play><player>EZEE090</player><screentime>12.23min</screentime><endtime>11PM</endtime></play>
<play><player>ESONY010</player><screentime>12.76min</screentime><endtime>10PM</endtime></play>
<play><player>ESAB020</player><screentime>11.55min</screentime><endtime>08PM</endtime></play>
<play><player>ENDT050</player><screentime>18.11min</screentime><endtime>06PM</endtime></play>
```

I have tried using sql loader but its not liking because my xml file doesn't have opening and closing tag. Even If I add it's inserting into just one row

Please advise method to load the file into number of rows based on number of xml body in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your XML in a root tag and then use `XMLTABLE` in an `INSERT` statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (xml)
SELECT play
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/root/play'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(
           '<root>'
           || '<play><player>EZEE090</player><screentime>12.23min</screentime><endtime>11PM</endtime></play>
<play><player>ESONY010</player><screentime>12.76min</screentime><endtime>10PM</endtime></play>
<play><player>ESAB020</player><screentime>11.55min</screentime><endtime>08PM</endtime></play>
<play><player>ENDT050</player><screentime>18.11min</screentime><endtime>06PM</endtime></play>'
           || '</root>'
         )
         COLUMNS
           play XMLTYPE PATH '.'
       )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25cf2184fe4335893f4b94ce7fc28fa8)*

---

If you want to load the values from a file then load it into a `CLOB` column in a staging table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE staging (xml_part CLOB);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (xml)
SELECT play
FROM   staging s
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/root/play'
         PASSING XMLTYPE('<root>' || s.xml_part || '</root>')
         COLUMNS
           play XMLTYPE PATH '.'
       )
```

Or, if you don't want to use a staging table then load the file into a PL/SQL CLOB variable and then use that in place of the hard-coded string literal in the first query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2eae57310dc1c3f671c313ac1c730dde)*